# how to break mapping table in order to faster query result and database size

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization, denormalization

I have employee number table and one group mapping table.

```
desc employee_tab;
----------------
empno int;
emp_name varchar(50);

desc group_mapping_tab;
------------------------
empno int;
group_no int;
```

i have 10 lac records in employee table, when i create groups of employee data insert into group mapping table like (empno1, group_no1).. (empno2,group_no1).....(empno100000,group_no1). the group is create corresponding empno goes in mapping table.n number of emp can can in n group. In group mapping table increasing very fast when new groups are creating.
plz suggest how to breaks or recreate group mapping table. now data in group mapping table reach to 60 lac and increasing very fast.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can each employee be in multiple groups?  How do you decide the group for any particular employee?

Comment: Thanks for reply. from the front hand user choose employees for particular group at this time for that group ex. group1 user choose 1000 employees. this (group_no1,empno1).. (group_no1,empno2).....(group_no1,empno1000) mapping insert as 1000 rows in group_mapping_tab. user can make group2 and same way can select multiple employees. any employee can join multiple group. this is basically design for in any group how many employees and name of all employees.now table have more than 1 cr rows still increasing very fast.

Comment: Since you have 1 million employees, your system seems large to start out. You're saying that, on average, each employee is in 10 groups. So, the Emp-Group table has 10 million records. (Is this going to keep growing, or will it stabilize at some point?) Still, the numbers themselves, and the structure, seem fine. What is the problem? Are you running out of space? Is some query working slow?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT mxn_distributor.MemberID,mxn_distributor.NationalID
FROM mxn_distributor
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT NationalID
    FROM mxn_distributor
    GROUP BY NationalID
    HAVING COUNT(NationalID) >1
)temp ON mxn_distributor.NationalID= temp.NationalID ORDER BY NationalID ASC;
```